# Integration of Facebook Comments

Tags: joomla-3.x, k2, facebook

I am making a blogging website and planned to use Facebook comments rather than the native comment system.Used the following extensions to achieve this:

- K2 blog
- SP comments for adding facebook comments.

Following are the 2 questions which are coming up:

- How can I get notification mail when someone posts a comment in the article?
- Most importantly, is it a good idea to implement facebook comments? or shall I go with native k2 comments? I chose facebook because my website is a simple one and thought this comment feature will allow fast commenting and social awareness.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6336487/how-to-be-notified-of-comments-posted-via-the-facebook-comments-social-plugin

Comment: @Nagarjun this link is perfect for my 1st question :) thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My opinion is to use Facebook, because then the comments are more widely shared if that's your objection. If the comments are in K2, they will remain just there and can only be seen by visitors to your website.

For getting notifications, you'd have to rely on whatever is provided from Facebook to do that. I'm assuming you are settings up a Facebook Fan page for your website, so in that account you should be able to get notifications sent to you from Facebook each time there is a comment if that's what you want. With a busy website, you could end up with a flood of message notification each day. Thought I would mention that so you are prepared.

Comment: yes you got me right. I have set up the facebook page. For notifications, I will check the comment settings in the page. I have created an appID but how can I link the appId to the facebook page to keep it both sync?